# Average only duplicated rows and replacing value in a defined column

Tags: r, duplicates, aggregate, rename, mean

I have a dataframe `D`:

```
surname   name   salary
Red        A      1000
Green      B       900
Green      A      1100
Blue       C      1000
Blue       B      1000
Blue       F       800
Violet     F      1200
```

Some row has no replicate in `surname`, some other yes.

I need to aggregate the rows only where surname is duplicated, to average values of salary and change the name to "X".

I tryed something using `duplicated()` but it leave one duplicate as original and change the others.

```
D$name<-replace(D$name,duplicated(D$surname),"X")
```

And also I was unable to average the values of `salary`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
D$name <- replace(D$name,duplicated(D$surname)|duplicated(D$surname, 
          fromLast = TRUE),"X")
```

---

If we need to create an average column

```
library(dplyr)
D %>% 
   group_by(surname) %>% 
   mutate(average = mean(salary))
```

#### data

```
D <- structure(list(surname = c("Red", "Green", "Green", "Blue", "Blue", 
"Blue", "Violet"), name = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "F", "F"
), salary = c(1000L, 900L, 1100L, 1000L, 1000L, 800L, 1200L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun but it doesn't aggregate the lines averaging 'salary'.

Comment: Thank you akrun, I add `D<- D %>% distinct(surname, .keep_all = TRUE)` to delete duplicates.
My expected output is:
`surname   name   salary <br/>
Red        A      1000 <br/>
Green     X      1000 <br/>
Blue       X      933.3 <br/>
Violet     F      1200`

Comment: @Valdarn8 in that case, you can change `mutate` to `summarise`